# How to use CASE in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, case

I have two columns in my table field1 and field2.

In my where i want to make a check if field2 IS NULL or not.

If NULL then my where would look like this

where field1 = 'myvalue'

If it's not NULL i want to concatenate the values from field1 and field2 with a + in between. Like this

Where field1+field2 = 'myvalue'

I tried something like this but i didnt work.

```
WHERE CASE field2 IS NOT NULL 
THEN field1+field2
ELSE field1
END = 'myvalue'
```

For example field2 has a value, lets say 7252 and field1 has 7311 then it has to look like this.

`WHERE 7311+7252 = 'myvalue'` and if field2 is empty

```
WHERE 7311 = 'myvalue'.
```

Can someone help me? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can translate this cases into two conditions , and use `OR` :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE (t.field2 IS NULL AND t.field1 = 'myvalue')
   OR (t.field2 IS NOT NULL AND field1 + field2 = 'myvalue')
```

Or you can do it with `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE 'myvalue' = CASE WHEN t.field2 IS NULL THEN t.field1
                       ELSE field1+field2
                  END
```

Comment: You may want to cast them to `varchar` first

Comment: I'm not so sure, they might be varchar's already, and they might be numbers as they should (maybe the myvalue represent a number) . @NickyvV . I trust the OP to handle it correctly.

Comment: Oh true, I hadn't thought of the fact OP might want to add the numbers..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COALESCE` as the below:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Tbl
WHERE
    COALESCE(field1 + field2, field1) = 'Your Value'
```

Eg.

```
SELECT COALESCE(field1 + field2, field1)
--
SELECT COALESCE(7311 + 7252 , 7311) -- 14563
SELECT COALESCE(7311 + NULL , 7311) -- 7311
--
SELECT COALESCE('Test' + ' 1' , 'Test') -- Test 1
SELECT COALESCE('Test' + NULL , 'Test') -- Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try: field1 + ISNULL(field2,'') = 'myvalue'

Answer (score 0):

If not using the `CASE` statement is an option, you could try something like this:

```
WHERE 
    (NOT field2 IS NULL AND field1 + field2 = 'myvalue') 
    OR (field2 IS NULL AND field1 = 'myvalue')
```

Comment: This is not `T-SQL` syntax, even though logic is correct :)

Comment: You're totally right, I was still in C# mode ;) Corrected my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your t.field1 and t.field2 are numeric datatypes.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.field1 + ISNULL(field2, 0) = 'myvalue'
```